# Dynamic google cross domain javascript broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, cross-domain

I am following this article:

http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2011/12/01/automatic-cross-domain-tracking-revisited/

which leads me to put the following in my site:

https://github.com/oldbie/xdomain/blob/master/xdomain.js

I have removed the `jQuery.noConflict();` and reverted to using `$` instead.

When I run the code on my site I get `$(link).attr("href") is undefined` when it hits:

`if($(link).attr("href").indexOf(this)!=-1){`

but if you look at the code in the link above it is defined when we do:

`var link = $(this); var href = link.attr('href');`

Is it being defined correctly? If so then can you see something that is wrong?

You can see the replicated issue here:

http://jsfiddle.net/uZFcU/1/

this html causes the issue:

`<a id="manage"><span id="ocPM" class="arrowDo"></span></a>`

Comment: hard to decifer snippets with `this` or variables in them without seeing where `this` or variable comes from

Comment: I figuered out what this is before it crashed.

Comment: I am thinking I may need to add something like `$(link).attr("href") != null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it being defined correctly?

Yes

> If so then can you see something that is wrong?

No

Since you didn't show all of your code, I ran the git code in a fiddle. I removed the `noConflict();` but that was not necessary. I also commented out the calls to GA functions since they are not defined in the fiddle. Alerts were added to show you where the code is firing.

Look over your code for another error or post all of it here because the git code runs fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/uZFcU/

**UPDATE** after new info added via comment

In your fiddle from your comment below: http://jsfiddle.net/uZFcU/1/

The HTML line `<a id="manage"><span id="ocPM" class="arrowDo"></span></a>` has no `href` attribute. So it's `undefined`.

The git script `listenToClicks` function is scanning the page on load in the `$(document).ready` function. When you have anchors or links like that, you will need to modify the `listenToClicks` to ignore them.

Change this:

```
$("a").each(function(index) {
```

to this:

```
$("a[href]").each(function(index) {
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uZFcU/8/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uZFcU/1/ I can replicate it here seems this html line it doesnt like

Comment: Thanks jk, will give this a whirl as soon as I am with my developer machine again.